# boneCp maven depenedncy not downloaded

Tags: bonecp

I am trying to configure boneCp and the maven dependency for bonecp is not getting downloaded. I have included the dependencies for guava and SLF4J too,

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency
```

Please let me know what is wrong
Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened, but cleaning the local repository and executing various commands like mvn clean package install, dependency:list, dependency:tree, forcing updates finally resolved my problem. The strange thing was intellij was not even showing compilation errors, only after intellij recognised the compilation error on BoneCPDataSource, it made suggestions to add maven dependency and then maven could download the dependency!!!!!! again I am not sure  what made intellij recognise the compilation error after so long!!!